# Increase speed of $match on $lookup MONGO

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a query in which i want to get data from 10 million records . Now i am using $lookup in the query to get data from a different collection and i want to perform a $match on only those results whose $lookup in successful i.e, the $lookup array is not empty.

Below is my query that i have written so far.

```js
[
  '$match'=>[
    '$text'=>[
      '$search'=>$query
    ]
  ]
],
[
  '$lookup'=>[
    'from'=>'library_books',
    'localField'=>'_id',
    'foreignField'=>'product_id',
    'as'=>'library_data'
  ]
],
[
  '$match'=>[
    'library_data'=>[
      '$exists'=>true,
      '$not'=>[
        '$size'=>0
      ]
    ]
  ]
],
[
  '$unwind'=>'$library_data'
],
[
  '$match'=>[
    'library_data.library_id'=>$library_id,
    'library_data.status'=>1
  ]
],
[
  '$limit'=>5,
  
],
[
  '$sort'=>[
    'library_data.status'=>-1,
    'library_data.out'=>1,
    
  ]
],
```

Please note that i have created an index on the other collection  using

```js
db.library_books.createIndex({library_id:1,status:1});
```

But still the query is taking 3 seconds to execute , so is it possible to reduce it further to around 400ms.

Comment: Shouldn't the index be on product_id? That's the field you are looking up in the library_books collection right?

Comment: Which MongoDB version you are working on?

Comment: silly mistake from my end , anyways it got down to 700ms , i guess it can't go down any further

Comment: MongoDB Version 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the index should be on `product_id`. That's the field you are looking up in the `library_books` collection.

```
db.library_books.createIndex( { product_id: 1 } );
```